# Raphael js get element's rotation

Tags: get, rotation, raphael, element

Is there a way to get an elements rotation value using the raphaeljs library? I'm sure there is but I can't find it anywhere in the documentation. I imagine its goes something like this .attr('rotation') but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`Element.transform()`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.transform) function to get the current transformation data as well as to set it.

You probably already know that `element.transform(tstring)` sets the transform data, including rotation.

To get that data back from Raphael, simply call `element.transform()` without any parameters:

```
tstring = element.transform();`
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Cool thanks! The rotation value was nested in an array so to get at it I did this:
var rotation = element.transform()[0][1];

Answer (score 3):

Here are four ways I've found to get a Raphaël element's rotation value:

```
console.log(el.attr('transform')[0][1]);
console.log(el.transform()[0][1]);
console.log(el.matrix.split().rotate);
console.log(el.matrix.toTransformString().split('r')[1]);
```

Specific outputs differ based on previously applied transformations.

- If no transformation has yet been applied, the first two will throw 'cannot read property of undefined' errors, the second will log `-0`, and the fourth will log `undefined`.
- If a previous transformation between -90° and 269.999° (inclusive) has been applied, all four log that transformation (though the third will be off by a few decimals, and the fourth will be followed by `0,0`).
- If a previous transformation outside the above range has been applied, the first two log that complete transformation, and the second two log a value relative to and less than 360° (and again, the third will be off by a few decimals, and the fourth will be followed by `0,0`).
- If multiple transformations have been applied to the element, these get pushed onto the array  that's accessed by the first two, and thus the first bracket-notation index would need to be adjusted accordingly (or it will only log the first rotation applied, not the sum of all rotations).

DOCS:

http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.attr

http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.transform

http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Matrix.split